# ask and edit an extra comment field

Tags: comments

I have been trying for two weeks to add a edit custom meta field to the admin edit comment form. I managed to show the field in the form, but it can't get it to update.

I would also like to add this field to the registration form and profile.

this is what I have so far

```
add_action( 'comment_post', 'save_comment_meta_data' );
function save_comment_meta_data( $comment_id ) {
    add_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'location', $_POST['location'] );
}

add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'location_meta' );
function location_meta() {
    add_meta_box( 'location_meta_id', 'Location of the Comment Author', 'location_meta_call', 'comment', 'normal', 'high' );
}

function location_meta_call(){
    $location = get_comment_meta(get_comment_ID(),'location', true);
    ?>
    <label for="location">Location:</label>
    <input type="text" name="location_meta_box_text"  value="<?php echo $location ?>" id="location_meta_box_text" />
    <?php
}

add_filter('comment_save_pre','location_save');
function location_save($comment_content){
    global $wpdb;

    $id = get_comment_ID();
    $text = $_POST['location_meta_box_text'];
    $data = compact('text');
    $rval= $wpdb ->update($wpdb->comments,$data,compact('id'));

    update_comment_meta($id,'location',$text);

    return $comment_content;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The get_comment_ID function was not working.
So use following code in location_meta_call function

```
function location_meta_call(){
    $location = get_comment_meta($_GET["c"],'location', true);
}

add_filter('comment_save_pre','location_save');

function location_save($comment_content){
    global $wpdb;

    $id = $_POST['comment_ID'];
    $text = $_POST['location_meta_box_text'];

    update_comment_meta($id , 'location', $text);
    return $comment_content;
}
```

Comment: finally got around to working on this and it finally worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function location_save($comment_content){
    $id = $_POST['comment_ID'];
    $text = $_POST['location_meta_box_text'];
    update_comment_meta($id,'location',$text);
    return $comment_content;
}
```

The get_comment_ID function wasn't working.

I'm not sure where you were getting the $rval/compact code from (I saw it in the core), but the compact needs to be compact('comment_ID') and the $id var needs to be $comment_ID for that to work.  (I think...)  Anyway, I wouldn't save it this way!  Just use the update comment meta function.